# RMarkdown child documents not rendering properly: ```{=html} shows in the output

Tags: r, r-markdown

We have a big interactive Rmarkdown document using shiny that we split into a parent/child structure to make it easier to manage, as per this [guidance](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/child-document.html).  We use tabsetPanel to pull different child documents into different tabs.

This used to work well, but it breaks when using R 4.0.4. Still works on my old 3.6.2 version of R.
When you run the parent document, ```{=html} appears at the top of the output, the tabs don't work any more and the text has disappeared.  There are also three backticks at the bottom of the output.

[screenshot of the output with unexpected bits highlighted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ArN8.png)

So far I have tried doing this in a different way using the following code from the guide linked above, but I don't think this will work with shiny and the layout we want.

```
res <- knitr::knit_child('child.Rmd', quiet = TRUE)
cat(res, sep = '\n')
```

Here's the code for the three R Markdown documents:
a) parent.Rmd
b) child1.Rmd
c) child2.Rmd

**a) parent.Rmd**

````
---
output:
  html_document

runtime: shiny
---

```{r, echo = FALSE}

library(tidyverse)

tabsetPanel(type="tabs", id="x"

, tabPanel("child1", value="y"
  , HTML(knitr::knit_child('child1.Rmd', quiet = TRUE))
  )
  
, tabPanel("child2", value="z"
  , HTML(knitr::knit_child('child2.Rmd', quiet = TRUE))    
  )

)
```
````

**b) child1.Rmd**

````
---
output:
  html_document

runtime: shiny
---


Here is some text describing the chart below

And this is some more text

```{r, echo = FALSE}

fluidPage(

fluidRow(column(6,
                
renderPlot(
  iris %>% 
    ggplot(aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) + 
    geom_point()
)

)))


```
````

**c) child2.Rmd**

````
---
output:
  html_document

runtime: shiny
---


Here is some text describing the chart below

And this is some more text


```{r, echo = FALSE}

fluidPage(

fluidRow(column(6,

renderPlot(
  mtcars %>%
      ggplot(aes(disp, mpg)) +
      geom_point()
)

)))

```
````

And here's my session info:

```
xfun::session_info('rmarkdown')
R version 4.0.4 (2021-02-15)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19042), RStudio 1.2.1335

Locale:
  LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252   
  LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                           
  LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

Package version:
  base64enc_0.1.3   digest_0.6.27     evaluate_0.14     glue_1.4.2       
  graphics_4.0.4    grDevices_4.0.4   highr_0.9         htmltools_0.5.1.1
  jsonlite_1.7.2    knitr_1.33        magrittr_2.0.1    markdown_1.1     
  methods_4.0.4     mime_0.11         rlang_0.4.11      rmarkdown_2.9.1  
  stats_4.0.4       stringi_1.6.2     stringr_1.4.0     tinytex_0.32     
  tools_4.0.4       utils_4.0.4       xfun_0.24         yaml_2.2.1       

Pandoc version: 2.6
```

Comment: This special syntax with backtick is appearing due to a change in htmltools. This is used to protect specific HTML part during Pandoc conversion, and it should not be seen in the output. You may have found a bug. 

You can deactivate for now this behavior to get the old one that should still work by setting `options(htmltools.preserve.raw = FALSE)` somewhere in your document or global R script / Rprofile. This should be a workaround to make it work.

In the meantime we need to understand why this happens.

Comment: I had a deeper look and I don't think this is an issue with the tooling, but it is about how the tooling is used. 
`knit_child()` will render Rmd content to md content. The output will be a character vector of markdown syntax. `HTML()` is used to preserve raw HTML strings in an app, and so it expects HTML string content. So `HTML(knit_child())` does not seems right. 
This is causing the issue you see because the result of `knit_child()` is not converted to HTML by rmarkdown (pandoc) but passed directly as HTML to the main document, meaning not process during the main document rendering.

Comment: Thank you @cderv for all your investigations - your answers are super helpful and `options(htmltools.preserve.raw = FALSE)` gets it working again although we have lost our additional CSS formatting (no major problem there).   For anyone else interested there is more detail from cderv [here](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/2180)  Thank you again cderv!